# Which version of reactor-kafka works with Spring 3.1.0-M2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, project-reactor

Running Spring 3.1.0-M2 with reactor-kafka 1.2.2.RELEASE yeilds the following on errors. Which version is compatible with 3.1.0-M2?

I am trying to create a reactive application that consumes from Kafka and writes to a MS SQL database using R2DBC.

```
2023-04-03T08:28:19.934-06:00 ERROR 22144 --- [event-tracker-1] reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers        : KafkaScheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.close(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)'
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver$CloseEvent.run(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:685) ~[reactor-kafka-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.doEvent(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:401) ~[reactor-kafka-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.lambda$start$14(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:335) ~[reactor-kafka-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.KafkaSchedulers$EventScheduler.lambda$decorate$1(KafkaSchedulers.java:100) ~[reactor-kafka-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.5.4.jar:3.5.4]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

From pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-M2</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-mssql</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Following is a segment of the consumer service. I receive a record, check to see that it is valid, then check to see if it already exists in the DB, finally, saving the record. I have tried a few onError configurations. The exception above seems to take precedence, so the error is not caught.

```
@Transactional
Flux<EventInterface> consumeEventDTO() {
    return reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
            .receiveAutoAck()
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2L)) // BACKPRESSURE
            .doOnNext(consumerRecord -> log.info("received key={}, value={} from topic={}, offset={}",
                    consumerRecord.key(),
                    consumerRecord.value(),
                    consumerRecord.topic(),
                    consumerRecord.offset())
            )
            .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .flatMap(this::exists)
            .flatMap(this::save)
            .onErrorComplete(UncategorizedR2dbcException.class)
            .doOnNext(event -> {
                log.info("successfully consumed {}={}", EventInterface.class.getSimpleName(), event);
            })
            .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("something bad happened while consuming : {}", throwable.getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `kafka-clients` from your classpath? What happens if you add it? Or, if you have it, what version is it?

Comment: Hi OneC, I did not have the kafka-clients added. It is now using version 3.4.0 which looks correct. Same as kafka-streams. Error and stack trace are the same with that library added.

Comment: `reactor-kafka` dependency should come with that already, though . Are you using Maven/Gradle and can share your dependency configs?

Comment: Dependencies added. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is no spring-kafka for Spring 3.1.0-M* yet](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka?repo=springio-milestone)

`reactor-kafka:1.2.2.RELEASE` is several years old.

[`spring-kafka:3.0.5`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/3.0.5) should be using `reactor-kafka:1.3.17` and also brings Kafka clients + Streams versions `3.3.2`...

The error you are seeing is related to the fact that you have conflicting versions of `kafka-clients`... `reactor-kafka:1.2.2.RELEASE` uses `kafka-clients:2.0.0`, and not the latest that your Spring starters are probably pulling

---

Also, Spring Boot Parent `-M*` releases are not "stable"; they are pre-release milestones...

As of this post, the latest stable-release version is `3.0.5`, which you can find on the [docs page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) (which matches the `spring-kafka` version mentioned above)

---

And if all this dependency matching is confusing, `vertx-kafka-client` is a simpler dependency tree

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-kafka-client/java/

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0.5 with reactor-kafka 1.3.17 is working as needed. Thank you for the support!